# How to disable any background interaction for modal dialog

Tags: html, css

I have a `<dialog>` element which I display via JS call `showModal`. In theory it should give me modal dialog (at least the name suggests it), but yet I can interact with the content in the background. For example if my main page contains some scrollable `div`, I can scroll it with the "modal" dialog in front.

How can I totally disable any interaction with the background elements? Currently my problem is scroll, but I bet there are more to discover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, I can give you an idea;
To create a modal dialog that completely disables interaction with background elements, including scrolling, you can do something like this:

```html
<style>
  .modal-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Semi-transparent overlay */
    z-index: 1000; /* Ensure it's above other content  (modal content must be largest that this value)*/
 }
</style>
<!-- Modal Trigger Button -->
<button id="openModalButton">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal Dialog -->
<dialog id="myModal">
  <p>This is a modal dialog</p>
  <button id="closeModalButton">Close</button>
</dialog>

<!-- Overlay -->
<div class="modal-overlay" id="overlay"></div>

<script>
  const openModalButton = document.getElementById('openModalButton');
  const closeModalButton = document.getElementById('closeModalButton');
  const myModal = document.getElementById('myModal');
  const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

  openModalButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    myModal.showModal();
    overlay.classList.add('modal-overlay');
    disableScroll();
  });

  closeModalButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    myModal.close();
    overlay.classList.remove('modal-overlay');
    enableScroll();
  });

  function disableScroll() {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  }

  function enableScroll() {
    document.body.style.overflow = '';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So it looks like the actually needed part is dynamically styling the `body` -- before showing dialog, and restoring it after closing. The extra overlay is not needed, because dialog backdrop suffices.

Comment: In your example, the `.modal-overlay` also hides the `button` that opens the `dialog`...

Comment: I think I didn't pay attention because I was focusing on the problem. But if you need help with this, we'll figure it out :)